# How does development on Visual Studio for Mac work when my .NET Core application also targets .NET Framework?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I don't have a Mac, I'm just trying to understand what happens when a person using a Mac wants to contribute to my .NET Core console application if its .csproj looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net452</TargetFrameworks>
    <RuntimeIdentifier Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' != 'netcoreapp1.1' ">win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Does it just work, except they can't test code within an `#if NET452` directive and they can't build the net452 executable?

And what if my .csproj looks like this?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' != 'netcoreapp1.1' ">win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: .NET framework is meant for Windows. From my experience if you specify net452 in your project and run it on a Mac (I tried with Linux), the .NET SDK will use Mono (given that Mono is installed)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand, are you talking about the developer's experience when opening the project or the end-user's when attempting to run it? I think I kind of understand the machine/platform-independence of CIL code.

Comment: What I gather it means is that it can compile and run with either .NET Core *or* .NET Framework but the same executable will not run on both.  So you will be able to use `#if` directives.

Comment: @user1676558 Your project is not "standalone" because the project file indicates that it relies on the runtime installed on the system (in this case net452 on win10-x64). So this project as-is won't run on a Mac. (no runtime specified for MacOS). If you add a Mac runtime (something like darwin) then the SDK will do its best to run it on the Mac using a net452 equivalent, which is basically Mono.